# Updating an object attribute from a method

Tags: javascript, node.js, scope, node-modules

I'm trying to understand why the following code doesn't work. Basically, I want to handle the database connection in a Node module, while using the same database connection.

Here's my module:

```
var MongoClient = require("mongodb").MongoClient;
var url = "mongodb://localhost:27017";

module.exports = {
  resource: null,
  connect: function() {
    MongoClient.connect(
        url,
        function(err, db) {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log("Connected!");
            this.resource = db; // Updating the object's attribute
        }
    );
  },
};
```

And my main file:

```
var db = require('./db.js');
db.connect(); // Outputs "connected!"

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  console.log(db.resource) // Outputs "null"
}).listen(8080);
```

The *resource* attribute is never updated. I suspect a scope issue but I don't know how to address it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The use of `function()` to define both `exports.connect` and the callback to `MongoClient.connect` causes the `this` ("context") binding on the function body to change to the function itself. To avoid this behaviour, use ES6' Arrow Function syntax, which does not change the context bindings:

```
var MongoClient = require("mongodb").MongoClient;
var url = "mongodb://localhost:27017";

module.exports = {
  resource: null,
  connect: () => {
    MongoClient.connect(
        url,
        (err, db) => {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log("Connected!");
            this.resource = db; // Updating the object's attribute
        }
    );
  },
};
```

Or you may move the `connect` definition outside of the object, and assign `exports.resource` through the use of a full object path, as so:

```
var MongoClient = require("mongodb").MongoClient;
var url = "mongodb://localhost:27017";

module.exports = {
  resource: null,
  connect: undefined
  },
};

module.exports.connect = function() {
    MongoClient.connect(
        url,
        function(err, db) {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log("Connected!");
            module.exports.resource = db; // Updating the object's attribute
        }
    );
};
```

Comment: Thank you. Actually just changing "this.resource = db" to "module.exports.resource = db" fixes the issue. That said, I think it's time for me to get familiar with the arrow syntax.